# Add / Remove SKSpriteNode in different function

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am newish to swift and can't seem to grasp this concept:
I need to create an SKSpriteNode in one function, then removed it in another and I can't quite get how to code it so that the removing function has access to the element created in another function. The situation: A power up node is created and displayed on the screen. The hero collects the power up and an icon is added to the bottom of the screen. The player can then touch the power up icon to use it, and then the icon should be removed from the screen.
I'll try to illustrate what I mean in the code below.

```
func createPowerUp() {
    var powerUpNode = SKSpriteNode("...")//add node to screen for player to collect
    addChild(powerUpNode)
}

func playerCollectsPowerUp() {
    let powerUpIcon = SKSpriteNode("...")//add icon to bottom of screen
    addChild(powerUpIcon)
}

func usePowerUp() {
    powerUpIcon.removeFromParent()//This is my error, powerUpIcon is not defined

func touchesEnded() {
    usePowerUp()
}
```

So, how do I structure this so that usePowerUp() has access to the SKSpriteNode I created in playerCollectsPowerUp() ? I know I could define the SKSpriteNode on a higher level and that would give both methods access to the power up icon. But is that a good practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. As you said, you can define the variable on a higher level to make it accessible to all of the functions. You can also declare it in an extension of your class. For example, you can do the following in your swift file (although i'm accustomed to using this in Objective-C, i'm not sure if this is the best case for you):

```
extension MyScene
{
    var SKSpriteNode *myNode;
}
```

Another way to get the same node is to use the `name` property of all SKNodes. For example, you can set the name by doing `powerUpNode.name = @"My Beauty"`. In your `usePowerup` function, you can then do `var SKSpriteNode powerUpIcon = self.childNodeWithName("My Beauty")`, where `powerUpIcon` is now the node that you named earlier (keep in mind you would need to track node names with this method if naming other nodes).

You can choose one of the two methods based on your specifications. If you use it in various other functions, declaring the ivar might be a better choice. If the functionality you described is complete, then using the name might be a better choice. As to your question on the practice of declaring ivars (instance variables), it most definitely is common and accepted practice. They have the functionality for a reason :)

Comment: I just realized he is using swift. Should probably update my answer hah.

Comment: Can you tell me what looks wrong? I used the apple docs to write all of the code here.

Comment: This is just quick pseudo-code to give you an idea of what I am trying to do, its not real code, but it is in swift.

Comment: Thanks, creating higher that the functions worked perfectly, for some reason I thought there would be a reason to not do it that way (though I couldn't figure out what that reason would be.)

Comment: Nope, doing so is called declaring your instance variables. That way you can gain access to a particular variable in all of your functions and subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you create your `SKSpriteNode` inside a method which makes it accessible to that certain method only.

There are different ways you can share the `SKSpriteNode` like returning it and calling the other method and passing it the Node, but the easiest would be to **create it outside a method**. So, right below your class declaration like shown:

```
class myClass {
    //declare node here
    func doStuff() {}
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Ok, creating the node in the class and using the function to just add it to the scene is an acceptable practice? For some reason, it felt sloppy to me to do it that way, but I'll go for it. Thanks.

Comment: Let's say method **A** adds it to the view, then **A** would (logically) need to be called first for the Node to appear on the screen. But every time the node is modified that change will be saved. So **A** moves the node to y=10. Then method **B** does it stuff on the node that is on y=10. Get what I mean? Oh and if you go with my solution, make sure to give me credit for it ;)